# Find roots. of $z^2=-1$

Tags: complex-numbers

for $z^2=-1$. we have $z^2=e^{i(\pi +2k\pi)}$=>$z=e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)}=cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi))+i sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi))$,

> we have here two roots .   for $k =0$ we have   $z=i$, And for $k=1, z=-i$
>
> did I miss something here in terms of roots.?

Comment: No, you didn't miss anything. A polynomial of degree $n$ can have at most $n$ distinct complex roots. So if you found $2$ roots of the polynomial $z^2+1$ then you found all the roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you missed something: the simplest way to solve this equation. Recall that if two complex numbers $a$ and $b$ satisfy $a^2=b^2$ then $a=b$ or $a=-b$. Now:
$$z^2=-1=i^2\iff z=i\textbf{ or } z=-i$$ and it is over.

Comment: Except that you assumed $z\in\mathbb{C}$ (think about $\mathbb{H}$).

Comment: @WhatsUp I edited my answer.

Comment: I think it's obvious the question is about complex solutions, not about the quaternions.

Answer (score 2):

$z=\pm i$ are all roots of this equation.

The fundamental theorem of algebra states that every single-variable polynomial of degree $n$ with complex coefficients has $n$ roots in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: $n$ roots at most or counted with multiplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Further simplify your solution

$$z= \cos (\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi) +i \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi)= i\cos(k\pi)=\pm i$$

to see you have only two roots corresponding to even and odd $k$'s.